# In Figma, using a min-width and the auto layout wrap feature, how do I make an element Fill if stacked vertically, but then hug after it wraps?

Tags: figma

I've got the min-width at 320 (narrowest viewport I design for) and then 599 at the widest, before it breaks to sm 600+. Those were the breakpoints our team agreed on, and I'm trying to work within that breakpoint.

In option 1 (left image), I love how the button fills when the viewport is narrow and the field and button are stacked vertically. In option 2 (right image), I love how Street Address fills and the Continue button hugs after it all snaps to one horizontal row.

I am not finding success in getting this to work in one frame, I feel like I'm trying to get the best of both worlds.  The new Figma min-width and wrap features are nice....but I cannot figure out this problem. I think I need to just do two different frames, or figure this out via variables.

[Figma file here](https://www.figma.com/file/9pw3PuICZHZOGI11RbWmej/min-width%2BHug--%3E-Fill-Problem?type=design&node-id=0%3A1&mode=design&t=HlHXcqmzTMEwevLR-1)

[image: figma problem animated]